# How to configure a Build process when your code depends on (local) DLLs

Tags: c#, azure-devops, desktop-application, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, pivotal-crm

I'm trying to configure an automated build process on Azure DevOps.

The problem is that my code depends on some libraries (Dlls) that are not tracked by my repository (and are not nuget packages).

**Is it possible to load in some way the dependencies and make Azure DevOps use them?**

I've already tried to create the pipeline following the Azure "wizard" but I'm not able to find any way to load the missing libraries.

I don't know anything about yaml files and how to use them so I just followed the instructions.

If possible, what I expect is to be able to configure a build agent that locates the untracked dependencies during the build process.

Answer (score 2):

There are the following tasks that you can use to download those dlls from various locations. You can just click add task and search for these. There are more complex ways like storing those in another repository and creating an artifact to use.

- Download Artifacts - FileShare
- AWS S3 Download
- Download Secure File
- Download File
- Copy Files over SSH
- SFTP /SSH download

Now if it were me, I would just add those DLLs in a lib folder and track those in your repository. That way everything is there that is needed to build your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact, it is a good idea to use the lib folder tracked in the repo but it doesn't solve my problem. I tried with artifacts but the build process is not able to find the references. As far as I understood, the correct way should be adding the artifact repo (as nuget for example) and the references on my projects as nuget package. But it carry too much work for me to handle it.